# Show that there are infinite linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, lie-algebras

**Question:** Show that exists infinitely linear transformations $D \colon \mathbb{R}[x] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}[x]$ satisfies $D(fg) = D(f)g + f D(g)$ for all $f,g \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ in which $D$ is the derivative over the vector space of all polynomial.

I know the definition od linear transformation, and I think to use the contradiction to prove this problem. But I not sure that my opinion is correct.

Answer (score 4):

For every constant $c$ the linear transformation $f \to cf'$ satisfies the given identity. So there are infinitely many of them.

Comment: I understand your idea. But just one sentence in the proof is too short, isn’t it?

Comment: No, it is not too short.

Comment: So that enough to conclude that there are many infinitely?

Comment: Yes, that is enough.

Comment: I have complete my proof: for every constant $c$, we have $D(cfg) = c D(f)g + c f D(g)$, so there are infinitely many of function $D$.

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my answer.